# How to turn continuously captured data into discrete samples?

Tags: java, sampling

First of course the data are not continous, but are randomly sampled. See this graph:

[image: image description]

As you can see I have some data sampled in not known interval.

```
/**
 * Represents sample from the graph above. Stored in ArrayList 
*/
public class Sample {
  public long time;
  public long value;
}
```

From these samples I need to compute averages at given sampling frequency. My problem is that I am not entirely sure how to calculate average values - they must be influenced by points near that sampling time, but increasing distance must reduce influence.

I don't even know what to search, I lack vocabulary on this topic.

Comment: averaging windows? kalman filters?

Comment: I have all data available at once so Kalman filter is not needed. The advantage of Kalman filter is that it can remove noise by making good estimation of what next value will be.

Comment: linear interpolation between two neighborhood points?

Comment: This seems more like a mathematical problem than a programming problem. Other StackExchange websites like Cross Validated, MathOverflow or Mathematics might help you provide the answer.